# Framework header files not included in pod lib lint

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to add VPX framework that is required for toxav to be compiled. I have my pod spec file like so:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
 s.name             = "toxcore-ios"
 s.version          = "0.1.3"
 s.summary          = "Cocoapods wrapper for toxcore"
 s.homepage         = "https://github.com/dvor/toxcore-ios"
 s.license          = 'GPLv3'
 s.author           = { "Dmytro Vorobiov" => "d@dvor.me" }
 s.source           = {
  :git => "https://github.com/dvor/toxcore-ios.git",
  :tag => s.version.to_s,
  :submodules => true
 }

 s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
 s.requires_arc = true

 s.source_files = 'toxcore/toxcore/*.{c,h}', 'toxcore/toxencryptsave/*.{c,h}', 'toxcore/toxav/*.{c,h}'
 s.public_header_files = 'toxcore/toxcore/*.h', 'toxcore/toxav/*.h'
 s.dependency 'libsodium', '~> 1.0.1'
 s.dependency 'libopus', '~> 1.1'
 s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'VPX.framework'
 s.prepare_command = 'libvpx/build/make/iosbuild.sh'
end
```

For what it's worth, the prepare_command creates the VPX.framework. I tried adding the VPX.framework files to the s.source_files and s.public_header_files, however they still receive the same error below when running pod lib lint. I'm not even sure if it's necessary to add it to the **s.source_files** or **s.public_header_files** since I believe the **s.ios.frameworks** already takes care of that?

```
toxcore/toxav/toxav.h:34:10: fatal error: 'vpx/vpx_image.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue. The VPX framework path was listed as below:
  **VPX.framework/Headers/vpx/{files.h}**

When we use vendored_frameworks it actually only looks under the *Header* folder for the header files. So instead we had this

**VPX.framework/Headers/{looks here}**

In which case I had to move the files under *vpx* , to *Header*

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue this week while linking frameworks in my newly created pod. You should use the --use-libraries option while using lint:

```
pod lib lint --use-libraries
```

This option is also available while pushing your pod to the master Cocoapods repository or your own repository.

```
pod repo push REPO_NAME POD_NAME.podspec --use-libraries
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you double check your framework path? From your podspec it expects to find your framework at the root of your project

Comment: Yes it is at the root. I believe my issue might be related to  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1824